# How to prevent instantiation of a C++ template class method when a specific condition is met?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I'm currently writing a generic vector template class (the geometric entity, not the container) with the following signature...

```
template< typename T, unsigned N >
class vector
{...}
```

... where T is an arithmetic type and N, the dimension. I would like to define the cross product as an overload of operator ^ (located inside class definition) and enable it only when N == 3. What I've have now is:

```
typename boost::lazy_enable_if_c< (N == 3), vector >::type
inline operator ^(const vector &rhs) const
{
    vector ret;
    ret(0) = val_[1] * rhs(2) - val_[2] * rhs(1);
    ret(1) = val_[2] * rhs(0) - val_[0] * rhs(2);
    ret(2) = val_[0] * rhs(1) - val_[1] * rhs(0);
    return ret;
}
```

Unfortunately, instantiating this template with N != 3, even though operator ^ isn't referenced, yields the following error:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::lazy_enable_if_c < false, flare::math::vector < flare::math::fixed < short int, 8u >, 2u > >’
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative to boost::enable_if in such case?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proximal cause of the error message is that, according to [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html), "The second argument of `lazy_enable_if` must be a class type that defines a nested type named `type` whenever the first parameter (the condition) is true."  That's clearly not satisfied here (unless your `vector` type just happens to contain `typedef something type;`).

You don't need `lazy_...` here.  According to the docs, that's only needed if the 2nd arg could be undefined (e.g. if the 2nd arg was `typename foo<T>::bar`, and the `bar` type is not defined for all types `T`).  `vector` (which here means `vector<T, N>`) will always be defined.

So definitely try getting rid of `lazy_`, or alternatively create a do-nothing traits class `template <typename T> struct nop { typedef T type; };` and replace the 2nd arg to `lazy_enable_if_c` with `nop<vector>`.  But my guess is you've already tried the former at least. :)

**And now I see why that won't work.**  According to the standard 14.7.1/1:

> Unless  a  class  template 
>   specialization  has  been  explicitly 
>   instantiated  (14.7.2)  or  explicitly
>   specialized (14.7.3), the class
>   template specialization is implicitly
>   instantiated when the specialization
>   is referenced in a context that
>   requires a completely-defined object
>   type or when the completeness of the
>   class type affects the semantics of
>   the program.  The implicit
>   instantiation of a class template
>   specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, but
>   not of the definitions or default
>   arguments, of the class member
>   functions, member classes, static data
>   members and member templates;

So anything that causes the class to be instantiated will try to instantiate declarations for all methods, which will fail when `N != 3`.  So it looks like you'll need to use an always-present method that hands off to a function template instead.  Don't worry, any decent compiler will still be able to inline through this:

```
template< typename T, unsigned N > class vector;   // Fwd decl.

template< typename T, unsigned N >
inline boost::enable_if_c< (N == 3), vector<T, N> >::type
magic(const vector<T, N>& lhs, const vector<T, N>& rhs) {
    /* Do the calculation as before... */
    return ret;
}

template< typename T, unsigned N >
class vector {
    ...
    inline vector operator ^(const vector &rhs) const {
        return magic(*this, rhs);
    }
};
```

This will work because the member function *definitions* are not instantiated unless they are actually called (or their addresses are taken etc.).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the in-depth explanation. Indeed, I had a typedef vector type; inside my class definition, but I forgot to mention this important detail. That's why I didn't understand why GCC was throwing this error about ::type not being defined. Also, I misunderstood the purpose of the lazy_ version of enable_if. Your explanation helped me to understand it. In light of this, I simply turned out to the outside version of operator ^ and it worked as expected. The error message generated when N != 3 is a bit cryptic, but this can be dealt with. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is "located inside class definition". I think you'd have less trouble if you overload the operator via a function rather than via a method.

I think it may also be possible to get by with just plain old specialization rather than boost magic once you switch to a function, but I'm less sure about that.